# Why are my AirPods Pro stuck on low quailty audio during discord calls?

Tags: macos, audio, airpods

I have my audio muted from the discord app, but it is still stuck being low quality. This also happens when using other apps where my mic is muted, but has the option to be unmuted.

Comment: This question misses an actual question, and some context like "does it happen only in Discord" and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Go onto Video & Audio on Settings and Set your Input Device to Build in Microphone and Output Device to your airpods.

This worked for me.

Comment: This is actually what I have been doing for the past while, can confirm that it works.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by turning off the mic from System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Privacy > Microphone.

It involves an app restart each time you want to switch between mic off and on, but it works.

Comment: This is standard macOS bluetooth for all headphones - high quality is only available when no microphone is in use in the app